# log4j logs to mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, logging, jdbc

I would like to insert the logs into a log table. and the setting op log4j.properties :

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=admin
log4j.appender.DB.password=admin
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO logs_2 (log) VALUES('%t')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

and I have tried also

```
INSERT INTO logs_2 (log) VALUES(''%t'')
INSERT INTO logs_2 (log) VALUES('this is an example log ')
INSERT INTO 'logs_2' (log) VALUES('this is an example log')
```

the table definition:

```
 CREATE TABLE `logs_2` (
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `log` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB 

DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

and the results:mysql>....command line....

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from logs_2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

what is wrong in with script??

Comment: the same configuration works wel on Windows Server + MySQL+ LOG4j and not on Centos 7 +MYSQL + LOG4J

Comment: Hi, Maybe could you try using %m instead %t

Answer (score 0):

- check the privileges of the user in MYSQl.

Answer (score 0):

With a little search I found another topic in Stackoverflow about how do log in database. It should help you:
[Configuring log4j property file to store in mysql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214140/configuring-log4j-property-file-to-store-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

**Please check your log4j.properties file path**

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
```

If you use log4x.xml use this line. I have this error  for log4j.xml

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (packagename).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig
>   for more info.

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.xml");
```

Create table

```
   CREATE TABLE LOGS
   (USER_ID VARCHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    LOG_DATE   DATE           NOT NULL,
    LOGGER  VARCHAR(45)    NOT NULL,
    LEVEL   VARCHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE VARCHAR(1000)  NOT NULL
   );

   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

    public class TestMain {
        static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestMain.class);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
            log.debug("Test debug");
            log.info("Test info");
        }
    }
```

log4j.properties

```
   # Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB

# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC URL
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDatabaseName

# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.DB.user=myuser
log4j.appender.DB.password=mypassword

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS(USER_ID,LOG_DATE,LOGGER, LEVEL, MESSAGE) VALUES('%x',now(),'%C','%p','%m')

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```