# Error while logging to databse , using log4j extra's DBAppender

Tags: java, sql, oracle, logging, log4j

I am trying to log to `Oracle 11g` database using log4j's `DBAppender`. [DBAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DBAppender.html) is part of Apache Extras project for `log4j`.

Have created the required tables by modifying the [Oracle.sql](https://github.com/apache/log4j/blob/c5f4279081091e562c44bb753f6e52dc6be5fa52/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/db/dialect/oracle.sql) script. Had to tweak `logging_event_id_seq_trig` trigger to populate `event_id` column in `logging_event` table. This was to avoid SQLException , resulting out of null values in event_id column.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE logging_event_id_seq MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE logging_event 
  (
    sequence_number   NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    timestamp         NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    rendered_message  VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL,
    logger_name       VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    level_string      VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    ndc               VARCHAR2(4000),
    thread_name       VARCHAR2(254),
    reference_flag    NUMBER(5),
    caller_filename   VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_class      VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_method     VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    caller_line       CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    event_id          NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY
  );

CREATE TRIGGER logging_event_id_seq_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON logging_event
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   SELECT logging_event_id_seq.nextval
   INTO :new.event_id FROM dual;
END;


CREATE TABLE logging_event_property
  (
    event_id          NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    mapped_key        VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    mapped_value      VARCHAR2(1024),
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, mapped_key),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE logging_event_exception
  (
    event_id         NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    i                NUMBER(5)  NOT NULL,
    trace_line       VARCHAR2(254) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id, i),
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES logging_event(event_id)
  );
```

I am logging to the database using Oracle JDBC Driver Manager.Here is what my `log4j.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="DB" />
    </root>

    <appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.DBAppender">
        <param name="locationInfo" value="true" />
        <connectionSource
            class="org.apache.log4j.receivers.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <param name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <param name="url"
                value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//some.server.name:1501/some.databse.name" />
            <param name="user" value="some_user" />
            <param name="password" value="some_pwd" />
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I have written a simple java program to test logging:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggingTest
{
    public static Logger log;

    public void logMessage()
    {
        log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingTest.class.getName());

        log.info("Entered the logMessage method");
        log.debug("This is a DEBUG message \n");
        log.error("This is a ERROR message \n");
        log.fatal("This is a FATAL message \n");
        log.info("This is a INFO message \n");
        log.warn("This is a WARNING message \n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LoggingTest logObj = new LoggingTest();
        logObj.logMessage();
    }
}
```

**I am getting the following error when I run log4j in debug mode.**  Whats puzzling is despite the error , I still see events being logged to the table. **I cant figure out what is causing this particular error. Any ideas ?**

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 23 and column 23
log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match "(renderer*,throwableRenderer?,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)".
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [ALL].
log4j: root level set to ALL
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.DBAppender]
log4j: Setting property [locationInfo] to [true].
log4j: Setting property [driverClass] to [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver].
log4j: Setting property [url] to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//some.server.name:1501/some.databse.name].
log4j: Setting property [user] to [some_user].
log4j: Setting property [password] to [some_pwd].
log4j: setConnectionSource called for DBAppender
log4j: DBAppender.activateOptions called
log4j: Adding appender named [DB] to category [root].
log4j:ERROR problem appending event
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid conversion requested
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.StringToNUMBER(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:832)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getNUMBER(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:239)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getInt(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:527)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getInt(GeneratedStatement.java:217)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:573)
    at org.apache.log4j.DBAppender.append(DBAppender.java:281)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
    at com.log.test.LoggingTest.logMessage(LoggingTest.java:15)
    at com.log.test.LoggingTest.main(LoggingTest.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.StringToNUMBER(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:825)
    ... 12 more
```

From my search on the web , I don't see a lot of people using DBAppender even though its capable of using connection pooling and log exception stacktraces (in comparison to JDBCAppender).

If my observation is correct , is there any reason why ?

Comment: No idea really, but poking around, it looks like it's expecting the trigger to populate `sequence_number`, and then [OracleDialect.java](https://github.com/apache/log4j/tree/c5f4279081091e562c44bb753f6e52dc6be5fa52/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/db/dialect) to use the same value, from currval, for the event ID? Not sure if it's relevant that getSelectInsertId returns a String. (In your version not sure how sequence_number is being set now. The original trigger is invalid either way...)

Comment: yes , it seems like data type error , could you post the query that you are calling when you call logger.debug() or any other method? i have used the DBAppender in the past , and you have manually to define the query that will be called instead of the default layout

Comment: @AlexPoole valid point. I don't understand what sequence_number is for ? How is it different from event_id ? I am actually not setting the sequence number. Its defaulting to zero. According to DBAppender  java doc , if JDBC driver supports Statement.getGeneratedKeys()method (which my driver does) SQLDialect is not required.

Comment: @AntJavaDev I am not setting a layout explicitly (there is no query) , as shown in my log4j.xml. For reference I was using https://github.com/apache/log4j/blob/c5f4279081091e562c44bb753f6e52dc6be5fa52/tests/input/db/append-with-drivermanager1.xml

Comment: yes you are right , couldn't find any suggestion of where can be the DB table or the conversion pattern . check this it might suit your case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214140/configuring-log4j-property-file-to-store-in-mysql-database

Comment: @AntJavaDev Yup I have used JDBCAppender in the past. But it does not use connection pooling , or log exception stacktraces. Which is why i was looking into DBAppender